# How to convert a button click to a mouseup event in separate js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, mouseup

How to convert a button click to a mouseup event in separate js files.

I have this button code in a html file (which is working without issue):

```
<button class="J_sheetControl" id="J_timingSubmit2">Submit</button>
```

When clicked it runs a function(?) in an external js file:

```
$("#J_timingSubmit2").click(function(ev){

  var sheetStates = sheet.getSheetStates();
  var rowsCount = 15;
  var colsCount = 7;
  var timesheetrowsdata = "";
  var timesheetcoldata = "";

  for(var row= 0, rowStates=[]; row<rowsCount; ++row){
    rowStates = sheetStates[row];
    timesheetrowsdata += rowStates+(row==rowsCount-1?'':',');
  }

  timesheetcoldata = timesheetrowsdata.replace(/,/g, '');

  const testData = timesheetcoldata;

  const dataArr = testData.match(/.{1,7}/g)
  .map(s => Number(s[0])) // Only take the first char as a Number

  let dataSum = dataArr.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

  let isSameAsRowsCount = dataSum == rowsCount;
});
```

I want to convert this so it runs on a click of a table header (on the mouseup event).
This function is in a second js file (function call needs to be inserted at the end of the if statement):

```
thisSheet.delegate(".TimeSheet-colHead","mouseup.umsSheetEvent",function(ev){
if(!operationArea.startCell){
  return;
}

var curColHead = $(ev.currentTarget);

const targetStateValue = localStorage.getItem('shiftstatus');

if (targetStateValue === "earlyshift") {
  var endCell = [14,curColHead.data("col")];
  var correctedCells = cellCompare(operationArea.startCell,endCell);
  afterSelecting(ev,correctedCells);
  //code needs to go here                               
}
```

I tried to rename it so it looks more like a standard function e.g. ColumnChecker()
But this just giving me errors that it was not a function on the above mouseup event.

I have resolved this but it does not seem the most tidy way (I have used similar twice already in the app). If no-one has a better solution I will use it as the answer.

```
var but_Open3 = document.getElementById("J_timingSubmit2");
J_timingSubmit2.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you could just add another event listener for your mouseup event.

```js
$("#J_timingSubmit2").mouseup( handler);
$("#J_timingSubmit2").on('mouseup', handler);
```

Comment: Thanks but sorry I do not understand that. I will try to read it again and see if I can get it. I have updated my question. I have a working workaround, though not very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not possible without a workaround.
I have hidden the button:

```
<button class="J_sheetControl" id="J_timingSubmit2" style="display:none;">Open Hidden>Submit</button>
```

I then call the button in the mouseup event (the original question):

```
J_timingSubmit2.click();
```

This then runs the function detailed above:

```
$("#J_timingSubmit2").click(function(ev){
```